# Fixing SMB adjustable contact to its SMB connector (Jack)

Tags: rf, connector, cables, cable-assemblies

I recently purchased an SMB adjustable square flange jack connector: R114413000 [[Partlink]](https://www.radiall.com/rf-coaxial-connectors/smb-adjustable-square-flange-jack-receptacle-with-cylindrical-contact.html).

In the bag, I receive the adjustable contact and the connector:[image]

How do I fix this adjustable contact to the connector body?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Manufacturers of connectors typically have detailed assembly instructions on their website. We don't know who produced these connectors, so we can't help

Comment: The part belongs to Radiall; more info can be found here:

https://www.radiall.com/rf-coaxial-connectors/smb-adjustable-square-flange-jack-receptacle-with-cylindrical-contact.html

But there is no info in the datasheet except for the connector specifications

Comment: Thanks, that is good info! Maybe add the link to your question itself(instead of just in the comments)?

Comment: This is a question you could send to Radiall's customer services.

Comment: I already did. Waiting for their reply as well. Will add a comment if they reply with anything useful

Comment: I contacted Radiall and asked them. I'll let you know what they say.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Radiall on this matter. Here is the response:

> I see what you are saying about the word "adjustable".  The TDS says
> "adjusted", I think that it's a typo on the website.  Regarding the
> "adjusted" description, I can't explain that either.  Perhaps we made
> the hole to hole distance different than what we would normally make
> our flange.  Nothing on this part is "adjustable" due to the need to
> respect the RF reference plane.

Regretfully, the Radiall person did not say how the pin is fixed to the connector.

Comment: As you said, the response doesn't really help. For now, I am going with a different part. But it is interesting to know how this part can be used. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I was wondering what they meant by "adjustable".